# How to search file contents of entire directory for certain key phrases?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

I have a web forms ASP.NET application; I'm trying to automatically generate a list of which pages speak to which SQL tables, as our DBM is going to attempt a database rewrite and needs to know which pages will be impacted by each change. This is a... very poorly written application that I've inherited, it's only used internally by a couple dozen employees.  There is little proper documentation, which I'm trying to fix.

I have text files of all tables/views/stored procedures in our database, which I intend to load into lists to be referenced.  What I'm hoping to do is write a small function (preferably in C# but powershell or other methods will work too) that will iterate through every .aspx and .cs file in our wwwroot directory (including those within subfolders), searching for any occurrences of the names in the reference lists. If it finds a match it should note which file and which table(s), then continue.

I don't know how to most efficiently search through the contents of these files, and I'm barely an intermediate coder so my knowledge of what is or isn't possible is quite lacking.  For all I know there's a much simpler way to show which pages speak to which tables, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Since you only have to do it once, open the relevant directory in Windows Explorer and depress function key F3.

Comment: Writing an app seems overkill to me for 1-time use. On a windows system, I'd go for powershell: https://communary.net/2014/11/10/grep-the-powershell-way/ If git is installed, you could also use the git-bash's grep

Comment: powershell looks like a great way to do it, though I'm wondering if I can use a text file with the list of all 160 tables as the search source rather than running the command for each table.

Answer (score 0):

Agent Ransack may be your best bet for searching through files/directories.
http://download.cnet.com/Agent-Ransack/3000-2072_4-10043846.html

Comment: Can I use multiple search terms simultaneously?  I've got about 160 tables I'm looking for.